# Visualization of x64 Windows Server 2008 without VT

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, virtualbox

Is it possible to virtualize windows server 2008 x64 on a server with VT not enabled? I know that using ESXi it is not.

If not, what are the problems associated with running an x64 MS Windows OS as the host, and then running guest machines as VM's off of that?

Current setup is 3 x86 VM's running on ESXi. I need to run Exchange 2010, so need an x64 OS to run it on. The motherboard is x64 capable.

Server = x346 IBM

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty bad news. No, you cannot run an x64 operating system without VT or AMD-V

I'd be very worried about resources. Exchange 2010 is a memory hog. Looks like your server supports a max of 16GB of memory (http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/xbc/cog/Withdrawn/x346/x346aag.html). Even if you max that out, splitting that up between 4 installs, one of them being Exchange 2010, is going to be difficult.

You could use Microsoft Virtual Server to virtualize the 32 bit OS's. I'm not sure how well this will play with Exchange on the host. Security and stability might be a bit compromised.

Comment: Using MSVS, would this be a suitable setup for a business server? Or is this just not 'enterprise' enough?